# Vector of a list of class objects and comparisons

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
vector<list<entry> > index;
```

Entry is a class containing a string key and another vector of ints that are the line where this key is found in a file that is read in.  I am overloading the == operator of my class to compare the key string to input, and if it matches I simply insert the line into the int vector.  If it does not match I will insert the key and the line where it is found.  So far I've tried just about everything to get this to work!  My operator overload looks like this so far:

```
bool index_table::operator==(string key, vector<list<entry> > index) const
{
  ......code......
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what to put in that operator.  Do I use the vector like this:

```
index[i[j.key]]
```

I've tried everything and researched all over Stack Overflow, but I haven't seem to found an answer yet.

EDIT:  Here is the class.  Key is simply a string, and it has potentially multiple lines associated with it.  That is taken care of in the entry struct.

```
class index_table
{
private:
    struct entry
    {
        string word;
        vector<list <int> > line;
    };
    vector<list<entry> > index;
    vector<string>::iterator it;

public:
    index_table();
    void insert(string &key, int value);
    vector<int> & find(string & key) const;
    bool operator==(string, vector<list<entry> >) const;
};


class text_filter
{
public:
    text_filter() //sets up the valid chars
    {
        valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-0123456789";
    }
    void map_to_valid_chars(string&);
private:
    string valid;
};

void text_filter::map_to_valid_chars(string& line) //takes a line and replaces invalid chars with spaces
{
for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
{
    if( valid.find(line[i]) == string::npos)
    {
        line[i] = ' ';
    }
}

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
index_table table;
string word, uWord; //altered word and unaltered word
stringstream ss;
vector<string> unAltWord; // the unaltered words parsed by the stringstream
vector<string> altWord; //altered words modified by map_to_valid_chars member function
text_filter textFilt;
int lineNum = 0;
string searchTerm, line;
vector<string> lines;
ifstream inputFile;
string findLine; //this is for finding a word in the line
if (argv[1])
    inputFile.open(argv[1]);
else
{
    cout << "usage: ./Indexfile filename" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

//parse words and lines
while (getline (inputFile, line))
{
    while (ss >> uWord)
    {
        unAltWord.push_back(uWord);
    }

}
altWord = unAltWord;
for (int i = 0; i < altWord.size(); i++)
{
    textFilt.map_to_valid_chars(altWord[i]);
}

//insert words and lines into the index table
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
    findLine = lines[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < altWord.size(); j++)
    {
        if (findLine.find(altWord[j]) != string::npos)
            table.insert(altWord[j], line[i]);
    }
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: that is no operator, you are missing `[]` before the arguments

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you mean?

Comment: So I'll be overloading the [] operator as well as the == operator?  Sorry, I'm still pretty new to C++.

Comment: @shuttle87 I think you meant `operator==`.

Comment: @0x499602D2, yes should be `operator==`

Comment: "I am overloading the == operator of my class to compare the key string to input" - What is input?

Comment: I simply forgot to put the == on here, but it is in my code.

Comment: The input is simply a word.  The program reads in a file and parses individual words that are put into this index table.

Comment: @gsoble We need to see more code. Please post a minimal program that reproduces the situation. Right now I can see that your `operator==` is incorrect (it should take one argument, not two).

Comment: Where is this "input" actually stored?

Comment: It is stored in another vector of strings. It's not part of the class.

Comment: `operator==` shouldn't be apart of `index_list` if you want to compare a string to a vector. Making `operator==` apart of the class means it makes sense to compare something against an instance of `index_list`. Can you post more code please, not just the declarations of the functions.

Comment: I added the rest of the program so far.  My main problem is accessing the individual elements of this vector of lists of entry objects.  How would I access the key portion or the vector of lines within entry?

Comment: What are you doing with all these vectors of lists?

Comment: operator== should normally compare two similar things. If you have a member operator== it should have one argument, normally of the same type as your class. A non-member operator= should have two arguments, normally of two identical types. Your operator== signatute makes no sense because it is a member and has two arguments.

Comment: While it's technically valid to have operator== that compares two different things, it is rarely a good style. If you need to compare your object key to some string, ut is much much more clear to write `myobject.key()==somestring` than `myobject==somestring`. And you don't have any overloading to worry about.

Comment: @n.m. One vector contains unaltered input, while another contains altered input changed by map_to_valid_chars().  It replaces any non alphanumeric with a space.  Then one vector contains the entire lines of input, for counting lines.

Comment: Also, that makes sense about not needing overloading.  I'm still unsure of how to access such a nested datatype, if I want to use the key member variable of the entry struct.